# Sqoop export duplicates

Tags: postgresql, hive, sqoop

Will sqoop export create duplicates when the number of mappers is higher than the number of blocks in the source hdfs location?

My source hdfs directory  has 24 million records and when I do a sqoop export to Postgres  table, it somehow creates duplicate records. I have set the number of mappers as 24. There are 12 blocks in the source location.

Any idea why the sqoop is creating duplicates?

- Sqoop Version: 1.4.5.2.2.9.2-1
- Hadoop Version: Hadoop 2.6.0.2.2.9.2-1

Sqoop Command Used-

```
sqoop export -Dmapred.job.queue.name=queuename \
--connect jdbc:postgresql://ServerName/database_name \
--username USER --password PWD \
--table Tablename \
--input-fields-terminated-by "\001" --input-null-string "\\\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\\\N" \
--num-mappers 24 -m 24 \
--export-dir $3/penet_baseline.txt -- --schema public;
```

Comment: what is the record count in postgres table after exporting data?

Comment: I am getting 1 million records added to the target table. Approximately 25 million. It differs for each run.

Comment: Only 1 million is exported?

Comment: Not all the records are duplicated.  Source has 24 Million and target has 25 million. So 1 million records are duplicated

Comment: What do you mean by 12 blocks - is it 12 part files in the directory from where you  are exporting data?

Comment: Yes there are 12 part files.

Comment: please share export command and sqoop, hadoop version

Comment: Hi Dev- I have included the sqoop command and version in the actual description now.

Comment: `--num-mappers 24` and `-m 24` are same thing. Use anyone.

Comment: Will that be an issue?

Comment: No this is not an issue. I observed so I told you..:)

Comment: Ok...got it....just fyi....to solve this issue I am currently not using sqoop. I am using psql copy command to load the Postgres target

Comment: okay It sounds good that your issue is resolved with another tool

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem now.

Comment: No. I used psql command to export. psql was already installed on my hadoop machine

Answer (score 2):

[bagavathi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7002385/bagavathi) you mentioned that duplicate rows were seen in target table and when you tried to add PK constraint, it failed due to PK violation, further, the source does not have duplicate rows. One possible scenario is that your Target table could already have records which **maybe** because of a previous incomplete sqoop job. Please check whether target table has key which is also in source.

One workaround for this scenario is, use parameter "--update-mode allowinsert". In your query, add these parameters, --update-key  --update-mode allowinsert. This will ensure that if key is already present in table then the record will get updated else if key is not present then sqoop will do an insert.

Answer (score 1):

No sqoop does not export records twice and it has nothing to do with the number of mappers and the number of blocks.

---

Look at [**pg_bulkload connector**](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_pg_bulkload_connector) of sqoop for faster data transfer between hdfs and postgres.

> pg_bulkload connector is a direct connector for exporting data into PostgreSQL. This connector uses pg_bulkload. Users benefit from functionality of pg_bulkload such as fast exports bypassing shared bufferes and WAL, flexible error records handling, and ETL feature with filter functions.
>   By default, sqoop-export appends new rows to a table; each input record is transformed into an INSERT statement that adds a row to the target database table. If your table has constraints (e.g., a primary key column whose values must be unique) and already contains data, you must take care to avoid inserting records that violate these constraints. The export process will fail if an INSERT statement fails. This mode is primarily intended for exporting records to a new, empty table intended to receive these results.

Comment: To test this scenario I added a PK constraint to the target table. When the job is half way through it fails saying PK violation. That's why,  I say Sqoop loads duplicates.

Comment: If there is duplicate data in your hdfs file. Then sqoop can not do anything in this. Sqoop will simply fire `INSERT` statements

Comment: There is no duplicates in the HDFS file. I took the ID that failed from the logs and then queried the HDFS table. I returned only one record for that ID

Answer (score 0):

If you have used sqoop incremental mode then there many be some duplicate records on HDFS ,before running export to postgres , collect all unique records based on max(date or timestamp column) in one table and then do export .
I think it has to work